# Sorting by absolute value without changing the data

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I'm looking for a simple way to sort a pandas dataframe by the absolute value of a particular column, but without actually changing the values within the dataframe. Something similar to `sorted(df, key=abs)`. So if I had a dataframe like:

```
    a   b
0   1   -3
1   2   5 
2   3   -1
3   4   2
4   5   -9
```

The resultant sorted data when sorting on 'b' would look like:

```
    a   b
2   3   -1
3   4   2
0   1   -3
1   2   5 
4   5   -9
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since [`0.17.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api) `order` and `sort`  have been deprecated (thanks @Ruggero Turra), you can use `sort_values` to achieve this now:

```
In[16]:

df.reindex(df.b.abs().sort_values().index)
Out[16]: 
   a  b
2  3 -1
3  4  2
0  1 -3
1  2  5
4  5 -9
```

Comment: I'd love to see a version of this that can do this across multiple indices, so that, e.g., if index1 can be either "Fruit" or "Vegetables", and index2 is any fruit or vegetable, and the values are the total spent on that item, it would be possible to sort the data frame by absolute value of the cost of the type of food (index1), and *then*, internally, by the cost of each type of fruit or vegetable.

Comment: just for everyone who is here and is searching for the values with the biggest abs listet first, change the code to: `df.reindex(df.b.abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index)`

Comment: An add-on question: what if I want to sort by multiple columns and only use abs() for one of them for sorting. Can I modify this code to make it work?

Answer (score 75):

### Perfect Simple Solution with Pandas >= V_1.1.0:

Use the **parameter `key` in the [`sort_values()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'B': [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]})

df.sort_values(by='B', key=abs)
```

will yield:

```
    A   B
3   d   0
2   c   -1
4   e   1
1   b   -2
5   f   2
0   a   -3
```

Comment: Had not noticed the `key` kwarg until seeing this answer!

Comment: `ttt.sort_values(by='B', key=pd.Series.abs)` also works, perhaps as well with older versions of Pandas?

Comment: @CactusPhilosopher: Not sure about the older versions, because according to [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), the `key` arg is "new in version 1.1.0.", [released on July 28, 2020](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html).

Comment: An add-on question: what if I want to sort by multiple columns and only use abs() for one of them for sorting. Can I modify this code to make it work?

Comment: @BowenLiu :   I can only think of another way:  ```df['B_abs'] = df['B'].abs()``` and then   ```df.sort_values(['B_abs', 'A'])```.

Answer (score 18):

## Towards more idiomatic pandas: Use `argsort`

A cleaner approach would be to call [`Series.argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) on the absolute values, and then index:

```
df.iloc[df['b'].abs().argsort()]

   a  b
2  3 -1
3  4  2
0  1 -3
1  2  5
4  5 -9
```

If you need to reset the index, use [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html),

```
df.iloc[df['b'].abs().argsort()].reset_index(drop=True)

   a  b
0  3 -1
1  4  2
2  1 -3
3  2  5
4  5 -9
```

Lastly, since `argsort` does not have an `ascending` parameter to **specify ascending/descending order**, you will need to negate `df['b'].abs()` to sort by descending order.

```
df.iloc[(-df['b'].abs()).argsort()]

   a  b
4  5 -9
1  2  5
0  1 -3
3  4  2
2  3 -1
```

---

You can do this with NumPy as well—use [`np.abs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and [`ndarray.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html).

```
df.iloc[np.abs(df['b'].values).argsort()]

   a  b
2  3 -1
3  4  2
0  1 -3
1  2  5
4  5 -9
```

Or, for **descending** order,

```
df.iloc[(-np.abs(df['b'].values)).argsort()]

   a  b
4  5 -9
1  2  5
0  1 -3
3  4  2
2  3 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

For series: `series_name.sort_values(key=abs)`

Then incorporating this with the dataframe : `df.reindex(series_name.sort_values(key=abs).index)`

Comment: how does this add to the existing answer?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 instead of thinking of the whole dataframe, just sort the target series / column of the dataframe and then re-index the rest of the columns accordingly.