# pandas sort values numbers negatives and positives

Tags: python, pandas

How merge negatives and positives number to sort the dataframe?

my column:

print(stockdata14['Dist. Média'])

```
0    -8.17
1    -2.13
2     3.23
3     3.60
4     0.74
      ... 
95   -2.45
96   -1.05
97    0.70
98    7.49
99    2.27
```

desired exit:

```
0    -8.17
1     7
2    -2.13
3     1.23
4     0.60
```

Comment: assign a new column which is the absolute values and sort?

Comment: i need absolute values for sort the values but a need the negative values on the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting by absolute value without changing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486263/sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data)

Comment: I'm saying `stockdata14['abs.dist'] = stockdata14['Dist. Media'].abs(); stockdata14.sort_values('abs.dist', ascending=False)`.

Comment: Why is 7 after 8.17 and not 7.49? Or did you just use random numbers for the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[(-df['Dist. Média'].abs()).argsort()]
```