# sort column by absolute value with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to sort this dataframe, on abs(C)

```
      A     B     C
0  10.3  11.3 -0.72
1  16.2  10.9 -0.84
2  18.1  15.2  0.64
3  12.2  11.3  0.31
4  17.2  12.2 -0.75
5  11.6  15.4 -0.08
6  16.0  10.4  0.05
7  18.8  14.7 -0.61
8  12.6  16.3  0.85
9  11.6  10.8  0.93
```

To do that, I have to append a new column D = abs(C), and then sort on D

```
df['D']= abs (df['C'])
df.sort_values(by=['D'])
```

Is there a way to do the job in one method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort pandas DataFrame with function over column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662826/sort-pandas-dataframe-with-function-over-column-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for position of absolute values by [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and then change order of rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df2 = df.iloc[df.C.abs().argsort()]
print (df2)
      A     B     C
6  16.0  10.4  0.05
5  11.6  15.4 -0.08
3  12.2  11.3  0.31
7  18.8  14.7 -0.61
2  18.1  15.2  0.64
0  10.3  11.3 -0.72
4  17.2  12.2 -0.75
1  16.2  10.9 -0.84
8  12.6  16.3  0.85
9  11.6  10.8  0.93
```

Comment: What if I want it sorted with descending order?

Comment: @Matthi9000 - I think use some solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order)

Comment: e.g. `df.iloc[(-df.C.abs()).argsort()]`

Comment: Hmm ok, when I tried that earlier, it did not order the df properly. I'll check again.
-> Yes, it works. Not sure what I did wrong earlier then.

Answer (score 5):

(From [my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486263/sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data/65442622#65442622):)

### Perfect Simple Solution with the Pandas > V_1.1.0:

Use the **parameter `key` in the [`sort_values` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'b': [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]})

df.sort_values(by='b', key=abs)
```

will yield:

```
    a   b
3   d   0
2   c   -1
4   e   1
1   b   -2
5   f   2
0   a   -3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

ttt = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'b': [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]})

# ascending order
ttt_as = ttt.iloc[ttt.b.abs().argsort()]

print (ttt_as)

# descending order
ttt_des = ttt.iloc[ttt.b.abs().argsort()][::-1]

print (ttt_des)
```