# Python: may we sort a dataframe by a "function" of a row?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

With a pandas dataframe, we can sort the dataframe based on the value of a row

```
dfObj = dfObj.sort_values(by='b', axis=1, ascending=False)
```

May we do it based on the absolute value (or more generally, a function) of a row? I expect something like

```
dfObj = dfObj.sort_values(by=abs('b'), axis=1, ascending=False)
```

If it can't work, how can we produce a row equivalent to the absolute value of row 'b' and then sort?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe) help you?

Comment: Thanks @rpanai ```df['m'] = pd.Categorical(df['m'], ["March", "April", "Dec"])``` How can I add a row instead of a column?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486263/sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you can do:

```
dfObj = dfObj.sort_values(dfObj.loc['b'].abs(), axis=1, ascending=False)
```