# How do I sort a dataframe by distance from zero value

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I'll start by saying I am a Python beginner, I did try and find an answer to this via similar questions but I'm struggling to grasp some of the solutions in order to tailor them for my own use.

If I have a Pandas dataframe as follows:

[image]

What code would I need in order to sort it as per the below whilst excluding the 0 value.
I would ideally want to grab the value closest to zero (assuming this is possible).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can set `abs` as a key parameter of [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Try this :

```
out = df.sort_values(by="Score", key=abs)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

     Name  Score
3  maggie      0
2   sally     -5
1    jane    -10
4   peter     15
6    andy     25
0     bob    -30
5    mike     50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [df.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and pass `abs` as a parameter. This will sort by the absolute value but leave the values themselves unchanged:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Sally', 'Maggie', 'Peter', 'Mike', 'Andy'],
                    'Score': [-30, -10, -5, 0, 15, 50, 25]})

df.sort_values('Score', key = abs)
```

Output:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Maggie | 0 |
| Sally | -5 |
| Jane | -10 |
| Peter | 15 |
| Andy | 25 |
| Bob | -30 |
| Mike | 50 |

This also works:

```py
df.reindex(df['Score'].abs().sort_values().index)
```

See here for more:
[Sorting by absolute value without changing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486263/sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data)